# Get the first element of my array $_POST['tableFields']

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I'm trying to get the first element of my asociative array `$_POST['tableFields']`.

```
print_r($_POST['tableFields']); // I get: ["id","usuario","apellido1","apellido2","email","password"]
```

I tryied using `reset()` method but doesn't show anything.

```
$campo = reset($_POST['tableFields']);
print_r($campo); // This doesn't show anything.
```

Comment: That's not an associative array. You can just use `$_POST['tableFields'][0]`

Comment: $_POST: An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method when using application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data as the HTTP Content-Type in the request. https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: @David Doing `print_r($_POST['tableFields'][0]);` is just get `[` :(

Comment: `$_POST` is an associative array, yes, but `$_POST["tableFields"]` is not.

Comment: @David Oh ... I get you, I'm sorry, you are right. So then, why I can't get first element doing `print_r($_POST['tableFields'][0]);`?

Comment: Ah so it's actually a string. Make sure the JS (or whatever other code) passing it into this PHP script is passing in an actual array and not a string.

Comment: Assuming it's all formatted correctly, you can just call `json_decode($_POST['tableFields'], true)[0]` to convert the string back into an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is JSON format so its a string value. You must do `print_r(json_decode($_POST['tableFields'],1)[0]);` or `reset(json_decode($_POST['tableFields'],1));`